# Replace first instance of a string using wildcard

Tags: python-3.x

I need to replace the first instance of a string in a sentence with 'good'. The string begins with 'not' and ends with 'bad' but can contain several words in between. Right now I only got to the point that if there are multiple instances of 'not *** bad' in the sentence it replaces everything between the first 'not' and the last 'bad'.

```
re.sub(r'not \w+ bad\b', 'good', s, count=1)
```

for example "The movie was not that bad" returns "The movie was good"
But 
"The movie was not that bad, not bad at all" returns "The movie was good at all"

Comment: Sounds like you need non-greedy regex

Comment: https://www.itworld.com/article/2786107/development/regular-expression-tutorial-part-5--greedy-and-non-greedy-quantification.html

Answer (score 2):

`r'not (\w+ )+?bad'` is the regex you want. You need to include the whitespace after each word if you want to capture multiple words, and use a non-greedy operator to capture them. Also no need for the trailing `\b` if you don't *require* "bad" to be at the very end of the string

```
s = "The movie was not that bad, not bad at all"
re.sub(r'not (\w+ )+?bad', 'good', s, count=1)
# returns "The movie was good, not bad at all"

# same thing with multiple words in between
s = "The movie was not all that bad, not bad at all"
re.sub(r'not (\w+ )+?bad', 'good', s, count=1)
```

The `+` operator is greedy, so it will consume all words between the first 'not' and the last 'bad'. If you only want the first `not ... bad` you use the non-greedy version `+?` to capture whole words, and the greedy `+` to capture individual characters within a word.